# WKT MultiPoint string not working in GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, sld, well-known-text

I have a problem with a `MULTIPOINT` WKT string (SLD file for GeoServer) that is not displaying at all:

```
<WellKnownName>wkt://MULTIPOINT((-1.5 1), (0 1), (1.5 1), (-1 -1), (1 -1))</WellKnownName>
```

I have also tried without nested parenthesis but same issue:

```
<WellKnownName>wkt://MULTIPOINT(-1.5 1, 0 1, 1.5 1, -1 -1, 1 -1)</WellKnownName>
```

The features are not visible at all, whereas they are with a simple WellKnownName parameter such as `circle`.

---

Here is the symbol I need to produce:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Correct, it won't be painted.

Marks are "stroked" and "filled", that is, their outline is painted as a line, and if a fill is available, filled as a polygon. 
With points one cannot do either. Instead of doing points, you'll have to prepare very small polygons.

"circle" is indeed a small polygon.

Comment: So do I have to repeat 5 times the `<PointSymbolizer>` tag or is it possible to just repeat `<WellKnownName>` tags within one single `<PointSymbolizer>` tag?

Comment: buffering your multi point should work

Comment: The problem is how can I positionnate the points on my symbol? I have updated my initial post to show the symbol I need.

Comment: @iant: How would you buffer the WKT multipoint string? `<ogc:Function name="buffer">` takes a geometry column to achieve that, so it allows buffering of geolocalized points. My situation is different for the points are part of a symbol... Could you be more accurate?

Comment: I'd use JTS and a short java program, or QGIS and copy and paste the feature.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I can't manage with your proposals... @Andrea Aime: I don't understand how to deal with `circle` in order to put together several circles on the same symbol. @iant: buffering a multipoint is not a good solution to me for the size of points will change with zoom levels as buffer is on the geometry column and expressed in meters. Then, I don't know Java and what JTS is. I don't understand what you want to achieve using QGIS. More detailed comments would have been helpful. Nevermind, I will manage with an external file.

Comment: @wiltomap - you can always ask a new question on buffering, comments are of limited length and not for extended discussions